# SAPI voice on Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, text-to-speech

Is there any way to use Microsoft Voices (Eva, David, Zira) for text-to-speech on Xamarin iOS and Android? The voices are great on Windows 10 but I want to expand my software to cross-platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the voices are specific to desktop and not available on Android. Voice comes with sufficient amount of data, not easily fits the mobile phone.

You can write a TTS server on Windows and communicate with it from Android.